# What GIS applications and services have been affected by the Heartbleed vulnerability?

Tags: security

[Heartbleed](http://heartbleed.com/) is the name given to a recent, very severe security vulnerability in the [OpenSSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL) library, used in a large number of websites and applications. It is being called one of the worst computer security vulnerabilities in recent history. Even [StackExchange was vulnerable](https://github.com/musalbas/heartbleed-masstest/blob/master/top1000.txt) as of April 8th (since resolved according to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228777/257358)).

You can read more about it in these [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/) questions:

- [How exactly does the OpenSSL TLS heartbeat (Heartbleed) exploit work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55116/how-exactly-does-the-openssl-tls-heartbeat-heartbleed-exploit-work)
- [What should a website operator do about the Heartbleed OpenSSL exploit?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/55076)
- [What clients are proven to be vulnerable to Heartbleed?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/55249)

What GIS applications and services have been affected by this vulnerability?

Link to any official statements by the application maintainers about the vulnerability and/or how to resolve it.

**Note to moderators:** Please mark this question and answers as community wiki, as this is more of a PSA than a Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [one statement](http://blog.safe.com/2014/04/fme-cloud-vulnerable-cve-2014-0160-aka-heartbleed/) I found so far, about [FME Cloud](https://fmecloud.com/) (which had the vulnerable version installed, but not in use):

> ### FME Cloud is not vulnerable to CVE-2014-0160, AKA Heartbleed
>
> The engineering team at FME Cloud has been working to assess the
>   impact for our customers in the wake of April 7th’s disclosure of
>   CVE-2014-0160, known as Heartbleed. We joined nearly every service
>   provider on the Internet responding to this critical vulnerability in
>   OpenSSL’s handling of heartbeat packets and conducted a comprehensive
>   security review in response.
>
> The servers hosting the FME Cloud website are using a version of
>   OpenSSL which is not affected by the vulnerability. As for our
>   customers’ FME Server Cloud instances, they are running on Linux
>   servers which have the vulnerable OpenSSL installed, but fortunately
>   the web application server (Tomcat) that FME Server uses underneath
>   does not use the OpenSSL library. The FME Server instances that are
>   currently running are therefore not exposed to this vulnerability. You
>   can test this by entering the URL here, http://filippo.io/Heartbleed/.
>
> As a best practice we have patched the OpenSSL package so all new
>   instances that you launch will be running the patched version.
>
> If you have any questions or concerns then don’t hesitate to contact
>   us.

Answer (score 1):

The [ESRI Support Services blog](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/) has a [statement](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2014/04/11/the-heartbleed-bug-vulnerability-what-does-it-mean-for-you/) about Heartbleed, which refers users to this [tech article](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/42405):

> ### The Heartbleed Bug – What does it mean for you?
>
> As you may or may not be aware, a recent security vulnerability was
>   unveiled for servers using the OpenSSL cryptographic library that
>   affects many different products and software worldwide. This
>   vulnerability has been codenamed ‘The Heartbleed Bug’, and potentially
>   allows attackers to read the memory of a protected server or client
>   and retrieve encrypted personal information from that server/client.
>
> As a result, Esri staff have been performing maintenance to validate,
>   secure, and patch Esri servers and infrastructure to close this
>   vulnerability and ensure Esri customers are protected.
>
> Please read [**the following KB Article**](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/42405) for further information regarding
>   the Heartbleed bug and whether any customer action is required for
>   your Esri software.

A note about the desktop software out of the tech article:

> Desktop Products
>
> - ArcGIS for Desktop/Engine – No customer action is required. The
>     vulnerable OpenSSL library is included with ArcGIS Desktop releases
>     10.1 SP1, 10.2, 10.2.1, and 10.2.2, but it is not utilized in a manner where the vulnerability is exploitable.
> - ArcGIS Runtime – No customer action is required. The vulnerable
>     OpenSSL library is included with Runtime WPF/Qt/Java releases 10.1.1,
>     10.2, 10.2.2, and the iOS/Android 10.2.2 release, but it is not utilized in a manner where the vulnerability is exploitable.

There **is** a potentially exploitable vulnerability in ArcGIS Server for for Linux, according to [this article](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/42407):

> ArcGIS for Server on Linux 10.2, 10.2.1, and 10.2.2 are vulnerable,
>   not as a server, but as a client to other servers which happens only
>   in the Print Service and Publishing Services when they connect to
>   remote ArcGIS Servers. That means that encryption for ArcGIS for
>   Server on Linux has not been compromised. However, it means that
>   attackers may be able to discover where ArcGIS for Server has been
>   installed, the name of the running user, and potentially even be able
>   to crash the print service.
>
> A patch will be available shortly to address the issue for ArcGIS
>   Server on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL (and by extension, PostGIS) *may* be affected, according to [this writeup](http://blog.hagander.net/archives/219-PostgreSQL-and-the-OpenSSL-Heartbleed-vulnerability.html) by Magnus Hagander, one of the core team members:

> ### PostgreSQL and the OpenSSL Heartbleed vulnerability
>
> Is your PostgreSQL installation vulnerable to the [Heartbleed](http://heartbleed.com/) bug in
>   OpenSSL? The TL;DR; version is "maybe, it depends, you should read
>   this whole thing to find out". If you *are* vulnerable, it is a high
>   risk vulnerability!
>
> The slightly longer version is that it will be vulnerable if you are
>   using SSL, and not vulnerable if you are not. But the situation is not
>   quite that easy, as you may be using SSL even without planning to.
>   PostgreSQL also not provide any extra protection against the bug - if
>   you are using SSL, you are vulnerable to the bug just as with any
>   other service.
>
> As the bug is in OpenSSL, however, what you need to get patched is
>   your OpenSSL installation and not PostgreSQL itself. And of course,
>   *remember to restart your services* (this includes both PostgreSQL and
>   any other services using SSL on your system). You will then have to
>   consider in your scenario if you have to replace your SSL keys or not
>   - the same rules apply as to any other service.

Additionally, Amazon made [this brief statement](https://aws.amazon.com/security/security-bulletins/rds-postgresql-updated-to-address-openssl-vulnerability/) about a few affected AWS-RDS PostgreSQL instances:

> ### RDS PostgreSQL Updated to Address OpenSSL Vulnerability
>
> April 08, 2014
>
> A small number of Amazon RDS PostgreSQL instances were restarted to
>   apply a fix to address the OpenSSL Heartbleed bug. All RDS instances
>   are operating normally.

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox addressed the vulnerability with [this statement](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/heartbleed/):

> ### Addressing the Heartbleed OpenSSL bug at Mapbox
>
> We have secured our infrastructure from [Heartbleed](http://heartbleed.com/), a serious OpenSSL
>   vulnerability that caused security on most of the internet to
>   virtually evaporate overnight ([good post by the New York Times](http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2014/04/08/security-flaw-emphasizes-the-need-to-change-passwords/)). There
>   is no indication that any data on Mapbox was compromised as a result
>   of Heartbleed, but as a precaution, we strongly suggest that you [reset
>   your Mapbox password](https://www.mapbox.com/account/#password).
>
> Here is a summary of how our engineering team addressed the
>   vulnerability:
>
> - We logged you out of Mapbox.com–you will be required to login again on your next visit.
> - All services were reviewed and updated immediately.
> - We rotated our SSL certificates and all other security credentials.
> - We reviewed all third-party services and worked with their teams to ensure that proper steps were taken to patch their vulnerable services and rotate their credentials.
>
> If you have any questions regarding Heartbleed or anything else, send
>   us a note at support@mapbox.com.